# How to use ClamAV Antivirus in AWS EC2 for scanning S3 Bucket object when any file uploaded to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, antivirus, clamav

I need to run ClamAV antivirus in EC2 instance that can help me to scan a virus for s3 bucket object when any object being uploaded to s3. Is their any blog or way that i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [S3 VirusScan](https://cloudonaut.io/s3-virusscan-aws-security/), which is a third-party open source tool.

Some of its features are:

- Uses ClamAV to scan newly added files on S3 buckets
- Updates ClamAV database every 3 hours automatically
- Scales EC2 instance workers to distribute workload
- Publishes a message to SNS in case of a finding
- Can optionally delete compromised files automatically
- Logs to CloudWatch Logs

Comment: is it safe to use in our AWS infra ? @jarmod

Comment: Is it safe, as in can you trust this software? That's something you have to decide. Do you run Linux? Do you use SSH? Do you develop software using third-party libraries? What is your approach to deciding if those are safe? This particular software was written by widdix and [Michael Wittig](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/community/heroes/michael-wittig/) who's an AWS Community Hero, if that helps your decision-making.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement the solution by yourself, you can use: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/virus-scan-s3-buckets-with-a-serverless-clamav-based-cdk-construct/